# Is there any way to transpose rows to columns in Knex.js?

Tags: knex.js

Currently is there any way to transpose rows to columns like crosstab() in PostgreSQL?

I didn't see anything in the documentation at https://knexjs.org that would do exactly this but maybe there is some group of functions that could achieve this result.

Current result: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGy5X.png)

Desired transposed result: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2qyj.png)

Comment: If you add SQL query which you are trying to create I can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)